# Conditional foreach Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Hello to the community;

I am in a little problem, I am not an expert in powershell but I need it to be able to perform some automated actions.

I need to validate that shortcuts point to a specific path example C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe

When it locates a shortcut that matches the search, it generates an action.

I am applying this small code, I cannot make a correct comparison of the values

```
$WSShell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$shortcutfiles = dir C:\Users\*\documents\*.lnk
$IE = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe"
foreach ($shortcutfile in $shortcutfiles ) {
    if ($WSShell.CreateShortcut($shortcutfile).targetPath -eq $IE) 
  
    { 
    Write-Host "$IE"
    }
 }
```

Comment: What's not comparing correctly?

Comment: The name of the executable is iexplore.exe, not iexplorer.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freddy,

The following code works on my system using PS 5.1 & Core 7.2.6.

Note: I changed the parameters to meet the .lnk files location on my machine. I didn't have any IE shortcuts to use.

```
Clear-Host

$ST = "C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe"

$shortcutfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "G:\*\BTB" -Filter "*.lnk" -recurse

foreach ($shortcutfile in $shortcutfiles ) {

    $CCFile = $($shortcutfile.FullName)

    $WSShell = New-Object -ComObject 'Wscript.Shell'
      
    if ((($WSShell.CreateShortcut("$CCFile")).targetPath) -contains "$ST") {
      "$CCFile"  #For Debugging!
      "$ST"
    }

    $WSShell = $Null  #Clear COM Object

 }
```

Note: I made sure everything was resolved via use of parenthesis in the IF statement. Also note the use of **-contains vs -eq** since shortcuts often place parameters on the target line as they do with my Scheduled Task shortcuts.

Sample Output:

```
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\2. Maintanence\7-Command Prompt - System Level.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\2. Maintanence\Enable Network SafeBoot.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\2. Maintanence\Enable SafeBoot.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\Office Tools\Office Ribbon Editor.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\Command Prompt as Admin.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\Everything Search.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\Regedit as Admin.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\Search Content.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
G:\BEKDocs\BTB\Shutdown ALL.lnk
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe
```

Comment: Freddy, You're welcome.